# propositions, using that which whose

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence correct?

> "It is an organization including the countries, all or a significant part of their population has a connection with French language and culture."

If not, how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

> It is an organization which includes all of those countries in which
>   all or a significant part of the population have a connection with French language and culture.

In the US and other anglophone countries outside the UK, formal (... of the population has ...) rather than notional agreement will probably be preferred.

Comment: Hi! I hope you are fine! I upvoted your good answer! I wrote an answer and the community downvoted it. Could you please read it carefully and tell me your opinion? If my answer is wrong, please let me know. Thank you very much! [1]:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343962/which-is-the-subject-of-generalising/343970#343970