# Which is the subject of 'Generalising'?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> **Generalising** still further, it seems possible that all grammatical
> variation between languages can be characterised in terms of a set of
> parameters, and that for each parameter, the language faculty
> specifies a binary choice of possible values for the parameter.

Which is the subject of 'Generalising', *the author*, *it*, or *all grammatical variation*? In my view, I think it is *the author*, but in terms of grammar, the logical subject should be *it*.

Comment: "The author" is the only possible subject.

Comment: It is an adjunct that describes  the following statements on a semantic level. It could be replaced with "To generalize still further". There is no explicit grammatical subject.

Comment: In such contexts, the unstated subject is usually "**we**" (the writer *and* his reader/s), who are by convention often treated *as a group* taking a "journey" through the book's subject matter *together*. Many writers shy away from using first person singular when exploring a subject matter, so you're more likely to read things like ***Let's** look at this in more detail, **We** need to consider X,...* rather than ***I** want to discuss X,...* First person ***plural*** is often more natural, even if it's not entirely "logical" (since the reader *can't* "dynamically interact" with the text).

Comment: Compare "*To state it simply*, he's a crook".

Comment: @TimR Is there a technical term to describe this usage?

Comment: I cut my teeth pre-CGEL and don't own a copy of CGEL, but from what I've been able to find on the internet,it would be called nowadays some sort of adjunct, possibly a "speech-act adjunct". http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/adjuncts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the active voice, the passage reveals that the subject can possibly be **we** or **one**:

> Generalising still further, it seems possible that **we/one** can characterise all grammatical variation between languages in terms of a set of parameters ...

I agree with what @FumbleFingers commented.

**I** is possible too but does not seem to fit in so well.